# Slim 3 with Eloquent - View MySQL query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, slim

How could I view:

- How many queries are being run
- Raw MySQL SQL query for each one

I don't know if Slim 3 has something similar to the console in Rails where I can view all http requests and database queries (under Development mode), that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would something like the following work, its based off the laravel debugbar

[slim-debugbar](https://github.com/yusukezzz/slim-debugbar).

Comment: Nice! I wish they had the SQL log

Comment: are you talking about the database tb/section on this examples page http://phpdebugbar.com/ see their example on the bottom